# Writing a program that converts binary into a text c++6

Tags: c++, binary, ascii, converters

I tried to look up stuff conected which the questions I have, but nothing seems to quite answer them in a way I would understand.

So, here I go: We have a file, which is in decimal. We have to write a program, that converts this into characters (basically we need to decode it).

So what I'd like to do:

1. Write a function that converts binary into decimal (already done)
2. Write a function that converts these converted decimals into character
3. Write the main function, which connects them together.

I'm stuck at point 2. How do I write a program that converts decimal into ASCII?

And if I am done with that that, how do I include the file nzz.in? Shouldn't I have to just write

```
#include <nzz.in>
```

And then it would be included?

Comment: to convert decimal to ascii use a+'0' where a is decimal.

Comment: You need to use input and output streams, you can then use your file as input and stream the solutions to the output. Look up how to use in and output streams in c++

Comment: You can cast `int` to `char`.

Comment: I wish it was so easy, but a+'0' does not work. I get other numbers and cast int to char is not a solution as well, since I get numbers ther as well

Comment: @Yalom Please see my answer and try with that.

Comment: @Yalom Please accept the answer if it resolved your query. Accepting and upvoting answers to your questions will motivate people to answer your queries when asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program will serve your purpose:

Let us have a header file called as `converters.h` with the contents as follows:

```
/* 
 * File:   converters.h
 * Author: Praveen
 *
 * Created on 13 December 2016, 8:59 PM
 */

#ifndef CONVERTERS_H
#define CONVERTERS_H

int toDecimal(int num) {
    int rem = 0;
    int dec = 0;
    int base = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        rem = num % 10;
        dec = dec + rem * base;
        base = base * 2;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return dec;
}

char toChar(int value) {
    return char(value);
}

#endif  /* CONVERTERS_H */
```

Now let us define the file in which the program has to run with the name as `testMain.cpp` with the code as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

#include "converters.h"

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter the binary number(1s and 0s) : ";
    std::cin >> num;

    int decVal = toDecimal(num);

    std::cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << num << " is : " << decVal << std::endl;

    char charVal = toChar(decVal);
    std::cout << "The character equivalent of " << decVal << " is : " << charVal << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output upon running the above program:

```
Enter the binary number(1s and 0s) : 1000001
The decimal equivalent of 1000001 is : 65
The character equivalent of 65 is : A
```

Please modify the name of the header file or the program name based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)